# Displaying objects in a certain order and repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
[ { id: 1, type: "test1" }, { id: 2, type: "test1" }, { id: 3, type: "test2" }, { id:4, type: "test2" }, { id: 5, type: "test3" }, { id: 6 type: "test3" } ]
```

I need to display items in the following order (using javascript)

type 3 first, type 1 second, type 2 third then repeat type test3 first, type test1, type test 2

I get an array of objects with a type attribute for each object. How can I efficiently sort the array so that I always get the following order:

type 3, type 1, type 2, then type 3, type 1, type 2, and repeat. So essentially, type 2 is always after type 1 and type 3 is always after type 2 or at the beginning.

For example, the array above will cause items to be displayed in the following order:

id 5, id 1, id 3, id 6, id 2, id 4

I need to do this as efficiently as possible.

Comment: How about you try something first and then come back to us!

Comment: You have a typo in your JSON in the last object: it is missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop through the objects and search for each type?

```
// order of types to loop through
var order = ["test3", "test1", "test2"];

// your data set
var objects = [ { id: 1, type: "test1" }, { id: 2, type: "test1" }, { id: 3, type: "test2" }, { id:4, type: "test2" }, { id: 5, type: "test3" }, { id: 6, type: "test3" } ];

// array to put sorted values into
var sortedArray = [];

// loop through as many times as the number of objects
// i = loop iteration counter, j = index of words
for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < objects.length; i++, j++) {

    // j cycles through the possible types
    if(j == order.length)
        j = 0;

    // find the word that matches the current type
    for(var k = 0; k < objects.length; k++) {

        // if word has not been matched already and has the correct type ...
        if(order[j] == objects[k].type && sortedArray.indexOf(objects[k].id) < 0) {

            // add it to the output array and exit
            sortedArray.push(objects[k].id);
            break;
        }
    }
}

// sorted result stored in `sortedArray` variable
```

See working example on [JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/s0cf8f4d/1/).